# Airtable / Google Sheets alternatives with a chat per row

Tags: project-management, productivity, spreadsheet, task-management, product-management

We have been using Google Sheet to keep organised when searching for a product to sell, deciding to discard or keep, the state of the product, who is leading and who is supervising...

The big advantage is the flexibility. We even have Apps Script to code (almost) anything we dream. But we miss something like a chat per row (so per product in our case).

We found Airtable that seems to fix that problem (it's a Google Sheet and includes a chat per row). But maybe a bit expensive & anyway I'd like to know other options (if any) before switching everything to Airtable.

[image: Airtable screenshot showing the chat]

Do you know any Airtable alternative (including a personalized table like Google Sheet, but integrating a chat per row)?

Comment: copied from here after reading that it was not the most appropriate place to ask: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189859/airtable-google-sheets-alternatives-with-a-chat-per-row

Comment: Mondays may work as well I observe.

Comment: It seems we are going to use ClickUp. Maybe not the best to solve this issue, but the team have chosen ClickUp because it also includes chats & task manager all in one. The Android App seems a bit buggy so far (writing support to let them know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We chose ClickUp. We have been a couple of months using it already.

ClickUp has different views. The list view is the one similar to Google Sheets:

[image: list view]

Then, clicking on a product will show the chat:

[image: task view]

Some notes:

- Originally, the imported Google Sheet had much more columns. But we have been simplifying the system by reducing the number of columns.
- I dislike that on the task view, the "columns" are not in the same order, but the last updated column is on top (so it's hard to find something on the task view if you have a lot of columns). On the list view, the columns have the order you decide though.
- We use ClickUp to manage all the tasks of the team now.
- ClickUp is a software with lot of lot of features and lot of customers suggesting new features and improvements. The customer support is quite nice, they usually give you ideas to solve your problems. The bad part is that some parts are under development, it feel unfinished (it seems developed in that way on purpose though). The good part is that, normally, there is a way to solve your challenge & it's kind of fun the crazy development and launching of improvements and new features.
- I don't like the "general" ClickUp chat. I mean: the chat not related to any particular task. We keep using Telegram for "general" chatting (now with the new Topic Groups) to chat. Slack in another popular option, but we prefer Telegram.
- I don't like the Android App: it just much underdeveloper than the desktop version

Please note I may not be updating this. So maybe at the time you read this, those things I dislike have changed and improved.